# What are some frightening characteristics humans and human culture (christianity in particular) would have in the eyes of aliens?

Tags: aliens, culture, religion

If humans made contact with intelligent aliens what could they find absolutely frightening about us and our culture. Culture-wise I am looking at christianity in particular.

Comment: Whilst a thought provoking and interesting question, it's really too broad and open-ended for this site. We like questions that can be definitivley answered (with references where possible), and that have distinct detailed parameters for us to judge what constitutes a "best answer". See [how to ask on-topic](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) questions for further clarification. You'd need to [edit] to give us more details about the alien race in question and their standards of behaviour and attitudes, else you'd just be fishing for ideas, which we also don't do.

Comment: This is too broad.  This site is built for seeking an answer to a specific question.  There is actually no way to answer this specifically since we don't know what the aliens are or what their culture is like.  If they are all herbivores, the fact that we are omnivores might scare them silly.  If they have a different (or no) religion, just the fact that we have religion might bother them.  As you see, there is actually no way to give you a definitive answer.

Comment: Science fiction authors from the classic age had a hay day with the idea that Christians eat their god during communion.  Any nature based faith would follow the predator/prey standard and have the god eating the worshipers.  Similarly, the whole crucifixion can be interpreted as an inversion of nature, with the weaker humans killing the stronger god.  They might get the idea that Christians worship the inversion of the natural order, which on the surface, sounds a little evil.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look up the Jenkinsverse and read some of the stories therein. There are lots of examples there both cultural and physical. Or google ‘Earth is space Australia’ if you want examples of why we can be considered hardcore for living on a planet where pretty much everything is trying to kill us. Other than that: I’ve got to agree this is an astonishingly broad question.

Comment: @JoeBloggs Another good one is this one story in Larry Niven's *Known Space* series (unfortunately I can't remember the story's title) where some Kzin go on a hunting expedition in Africa. They are shocked at how dangerous Earth is, and thus conclude at the end of the story that "No wonder they always beat us! We would have stayed away; they came back to hunt."

Comment: I considered editing this question; however, the changes would go beyond editing. As a result, I am instead asking a new question.

Comment: There actually are some things that are rare or specific to humanity among animals in general that might be considered frightening, and hence alien species would likely not have them and consider them frightening. Unfortunately this question got closed as I was writing my answer and it is way too long to put in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

*it depends on what your aliens consider frightening*

Though it might not be a satisfying answer, what your aliens will consider horrendous is heavily linked to their society and world views. A group of peaceful aliens would be shocked to see us watching sports like UFC, the existence of martial arts, and the mere existence of terrorist groups throughout the world, while the exact same species built on a violent social basis could see it as normal.

In addition, if your aliens have in their world creatures that resemble cats as the Apex predators, they'd be shocked to see us playing with them and treating them as pets. The very fact that we're sturdier than many animals could be a nightmarish thing (remember that in our early days we'd basically hunt by stalking prey till they were too exhausted to run any longer or properly resisting as we killed them, which is in itself a terrifying concept even for us. Also we can usually shrug some wounds that would be lethal to many animals due to our intellect and group work).

Also, they could see religion as a whole as creepy, and I'm not even talking about the violent acts. The simple concept of someone refusing to consume certain foods or eat altogether for long periods or even during their entire lives purely out of faith could be seen to aliens without religion as extremist behavior. Same for the apparent adoration of images and symbols, the act of praying and many other actions and behaviors characteristic to various religions (reminder that it's unlikely that the aliens wil not look at, say, a cross and immediately think "oh ok it's a symbol for Jesus Christ and his sacrifice in the sake of humanity"). Alternatively, for aliens with extremely religious behavior the concept of atheists simply existing could be outrageous, even scary to them.

Just like a western person might be shocked to learn in some Asian countries dogs are treated as food, how your aliens will perceive us as a whole depends entirely on themselves. An extremely extremist group of religious aliens might even see the actions of the inquisition and the crusades as examples of ideal behavior, considering the wrongs done in these events as "necessary evil".

Comment: "Adoration of images"? Who does that? Christians most definitely don't. Icons are [venerated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneration), not adored; only God is adored.

Comment: @AlexP that's a subtlety for theologists, not for laymen, even less for aliens. When the Bible was presented to indigenous stating that it "contained God's word" the first reaction was to put it close to ear and throw it away once no word was  heard. But we have had a good dose of kills for the filioque, too...

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica: Given the [long and violent disputes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iconoclasm) about the veneration of icons, I would have hoped that the distinction was clearly established by now...

Comment: @AlexP it is (hopefully) for the people with high studies. For common folks, mmm... not yet

Comment: @AlexP, you're still treating this on the perspective of someone who knows and is used to the symbols and rituals. My answer focused on potential points of view from the speculative aliens. For an alien being, much like to an indigenous person who never had contact with religion, it won't be immediately obvious to them that the statue, symbol or image people are venerating is representing something else, unless they too have something similar in their own culture. Should the aliens not have such things, they'd likely find this strange or even frightening.

Comment: Well, we never ever had a society on Earth which did not use symbols and rituals. Describing a society which *does not* use symbols and rituals would be most interesting, I agree.

Answer (score 1):

I don’t know what your aliens look like, but humans could certainly appear ugly from their point of view. Their organs that evolved to perform the same tasks as human organs may look very different and would therefore find humans ugly.

Like @ShadoCat said, they may not even have a religion and would view humans as childlike and unintelligent, much like the belief in Santa Claus.

They may find any of the following practices of Christianity frightening:

- The prohibition of homosexuality in certain denominations if they reproduce asexually
- The Eucharist, as they may view the Christian god as weak since they view the Eucharist as eating their god (like @ShadoCat)
- They may view the Christian god as evil and the faith as demonic since some denominations believe that he puts people to Hell
- They may view Christianity as unscientific if their belief on the origin of the world has the most evidence according to their research
- They may be confused at the lack of representation of them in the Bible and feel that Christianity was created to promote human dominance